# Show up a title box,when you click a button

Tags: php, validation, title

I am wondering if there is a way to show a title box containing a message when you click a button,or as a better example,you have an input,and after php script evalute the value,and it's wrong,a title box will show up , saying "Wrong" ... Any ideas? Just with php if its possible!!

EDIT:
What i am looking for,is not for a simple message like:

```
echo '<p></p>';
```

Of course i know how to do that,its basic...
I was just wondering if a TITLE box can show up,like this:

```
  <input type=text title='Wrong'>
```

but after the value its evaluated...

Comment: PHP is server side script.. So if you allow the page to be refreshed you can use PHP, If the page isn't allowed to be refreshed.. You will have to use jquery for this..

Comment: is not a problem,it can be refreshed ... but anyway i have no idea how to do it in php

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php

Comment: What do you mean by a title box?

Comment: `<input type=text title='Wrong'>` => `title` is not an attribute for the `input` tag, this code won't display "Wrong" on the screen.

Comment: It was just an example,the title can be set to a link or something else....

Comment: You can fill the placeholder of an input field?

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this by setting a GET or POST value with the button:

html:

```
<form method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="postvalue" value="yes">
</form>
```

php:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['postvalue'])){
echo "<p>messageboxtoshow</p>";
}
?>
```

however a solution with javascript would work way better and would look way more userfriendly, and this only works on page refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Try this sample one

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
echo "<p> Your message</p>";
}
?>
<form action=<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?> method="post" >
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean validation per input field?
You can use JQuery for that.

I made a fiddle to give you a visual idea: http://jsfiddle.net/4b3tzreo/

For example, if this is your form:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="left">
        Username
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="left">
        Password
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="left">
        <button id="submit">Submit values</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can add a class to it when the input value is empty, like this:

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
   var username = $('#username').val();
    var password = $('#password').val()

    if(username === '') {
         $('#username').addClass('error');  
        alert('username is not filled');
    }

    if(password === '') {
        $('#password').addClass('error');
        alert('password is not filled');
});
```